# Meaning of "in 24 hours"

Tags: meaning, grammar

I am sorry if this question is not appropriate for this site, but I am confused with the following sentence. *"First settle your balance then try again **in 24 hours"***. My question is, does the sentence advise to try **After 24 hours** or **Within 24 hours**. When shall the user try again? Is it valid to try before 24 hours is elapsed?

Comment: Financial transactions still aren't usually fully processed immediately. Most likely the server for the site you're looking at runs an update once every 24 hours, so if you wait at least that long *after* you've settled your outstanding balance, it should be flagged as "complete" rather than "pending verification". Depending on what time of day they run the daily update, you might be able to carry out your "stalled" transaction sooner, but they say 24 hours because that's the *longest* you should have to wait. If it still doesn't work then, contact them - because *something has gone wrong*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Come back in 24 hours" or "Try again in 24 hours" generally means "Come back (or try again) ***after* 24 hours have elapsed**." For example, if you get such a message at noon on Thursday, you should come back no sooner than noon on Friday.

However, that guidance applies only to the general case. In the practical sense, this might be longer than you actually would need to wait. As FumbleFingers says in his comment, there are times when 24 hours represents the worst-case scenario only, so, if you showed up two hours before noon, there's a good chance you might find the matter already settled.

Sometimes it's easier to give a single message that represents the worst-case, instead of giving everyone a custom message that depends on current workloads. Consider an ice rink with a sign that says skates can be sharpened in 24 hours. The 24 hours is really more of a deadline for the rink than it is an estimate of how long it will take to sharpen the skates.

Comment: Sure. Times like this are often a worst case. If they tell you to come back in 24 hours and they really got whatever it was done in 1 hour, it will be ready when you come back as promised. If they say to come back in 1 hour and it really takes them 3 hours, then when you come back you'll be disappointed. If you try again an hour later you'll be disappointed again. Unless there's a desperate hurry, it's better to make a somewhat pessimistic promise that you can keep than an optimistic promise that maybe you can't.